# Django queryset iteration

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to iterate through the date entries and want compare them to other dates, but I get only one value, what am I doing wrong ?

```
    @property
    def mathe2(self):
        for i in self.lehrertabelle_set.all():
            return i.from_date
```

Comment: `return` will return the first `i.from_date`, so it will not look for the second, third, etc.

Comment: how can I make it to look for all of them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@property
def mathe2(self):
    date_list = []
    now = datetime.now()
    for i in self.lehrertabelle_set.all():
        if i.date == now:
            date_list.append(i)
    return date_list
```

Comment: I will try out, this seems promising.  My goal is to compare it if it is in range in given date

Comment: What do you want to return if some date is in the given date range? Just `True` or `False`? Or maybe a list of `lehrertabelle` instances that are in given range?

Comment: a list of given instances in range. And those  as sum

Comment: @property
    def prognose_rechnung(self):
        if self.Prognose_Datum <= self.mathe2 or self.Prognose_Datum >= self.mathe2:
            return self.prognose_stunden_1
like that but prognose_stunden_1 and then 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement returns value and exits the method so no more values will be checked.

If you want to iterate through all of them and check something then use:

```
for i in self.lehrertabelle_set.all():
    if i.from_date == something:
        # do something
```

If you want to get a list of `lehrertabelle` in a given range then `filter` queryset using `gte` (greater then or equal) and `lte` (less then or equal):

```
qs_in_range = self.lehrertabelle_set.filter(from_date__gte=start_date, from_date__lte=end_date)
```

you can read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: The second one is what I want, but I need every from date. My goal is it to check for all dates and then sum other values together, if date is changed or none then sum default values

Comment: Ok. Update original question with all new details and we will figure out something. You can write some pseudo-code that will expain what you want to do

Comment: okay with your solution I got it, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

sorry need to correct myself, joshlsullivan answer helped me solving my issue.
after testing all through, I got the sum of everything when the date was the same on every value, and that was not my goal. I needed that every entry is compared to each other and based on true or false it calcs the trues together this is now my solution for that. But I thank everybody who helped me out!

```
  @property
    def mathe2(self):
        einzelne_werte = []
        for i in self.lehrertabelle_set.all():
            if i.von_Datum == self.Prognose_Datum:
                einzelne_werte.append(i.Stunden)
        return sum(einzelne_werte) / 28
```